# How to give cloudformation parameter file instead of listing parameters in ansible playbook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create cloudformation stack using ansible playbook. Is there any parameter in ansible instead of "template_parameters" to  mention cloudformation parameters as an input json file. I want to give parameters file complete path in ansible instead of listing out parameters in "template-parameters". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the [`file` lookup](http://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_lookups.html#intro-to-lookups-getting-file-contents) :

```
- name: Launch stack
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: "mystack"
    state: "present"
    region: "us-east-1"
    template: "files/stack-template.json"
    template_parameters: "{{ lookup('file', 'files/stack-parameters.json') | from_json }}"
```

Comment: Got this error -

argument template_parameters is of type <type 'str'> and we were unable to convert to dict: dictionary requested, could not parse JSON or key=value"

Comment: What version of Ansible are you using?